# PowerBI: "Show as a table" missing rows

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a PowerBi Report displaying a graph of rainfall for multiple locations.

The source data is hourly.

When I select the feature "Show as a table", The table is missing rows. (see below)

[image: Show as a table]

If I export the data the source records are there.

Why is PowerBI skipping rows and what can I do to fix this?

It's doing this in Desktop and well as deployed.

Comment: Try to sort on Date Time column and check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer... and it's a bit embarrasing.

The visual has a limit on the number of records it can render. (I don't know what that limit is.) Once the visual exceeds that limit it displays an "i" in the top right hand corner. If you hold your mouse over it it says:

[image: tooltip]

When I click "Show as a table" The table view also displays the "i".

If you click for details it gives a longer description

[image]

If I drill down so that less data is rendered the "i" goes away and records are displayed without gaps.